# getting work days of week

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I am working on a student schedule and i have a problem. I need to have an array of days of current week, and of next week. So if today is Tue 11.11 i need to somehow get Mon 10.11 Tue 11.11 Wed 12.11 Thurs 13.11 Friday 14.11, and the same days of the next week with it dates. This one i need to do in my program such function, when user can pick any day of week and set his schedule on this day. I looked everywhere on stack overflow, but all solutions was not exact. Can you help me? Here is some of my attempts.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *beginningOfThisWeek;
NSDate *beginningOfNextWeek;

NSTimeInterval durationOfWeek;
[calendar setFirstWeekday:3];
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth
            startDate:&beginningOfThisWeek
             interval:&durationOfWeek
              forDate:now];

beginningOfNextWeek = [beginningOfThisWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:durationOfWeek];


NSDate *date = beginningOfThisWeek;
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

while (![beginningOfNextWeek compare:date]  == NSOrderedSame) {
    [dateArray addObject:date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:date];
    comps.day +=1;
    date = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

}
NSLog(@"%@",dateArray);
NSLog(@"%@",now);
```

but in log i get something like:

```
2014-11-11 18:37:29.479 StudentSchedule[3964:436389] (
    "2014-11-10 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-11-11 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-11-12 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-11-13 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-11-14 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-11-15 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2014-11-16 22:00:00 +0000"
```

i have dates, but 7, and i don't have names of weekdays, which is very important. I know that my question is very simple, but i am tired of looking for the right answer.

Comment: Subtract 48 hours from `durationOfWeek` before using `dateByAddingTimeInterval`.

Comment: how should i do this? adding 2 NSTimeInterval?

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is another name for `double`. It represents a number of seconds. If you subtract `48*60*60`, you'll be subtracting approximately two days, landing you on the right calendar date for the end of your work week.

Comment: durationOfWeek = durationOfWeek - ( 48 * 60 * 60);
understood. and in my array i have this dates, and what should i do to have the names of weekdays in the Array of NSStrings?

Comment: Create an `NSDateFormatter` and access the `weekdaySymbols` property.

Comment: The log output is for the raw `NSDate` objects you calculated. Don't worry about their output format. You are just seeing the results of the `description` method. When you really show those dates to the user, use `NSDateFormatter` to show them in whatever format you really want. Your issue now is to get the correct dates, not worry about the format.

Comment: No, don't do this. 48*60*60 is NOT two days. Let me add an answer.

Comment: @SpencerReid Do not do what Ian is stating. Do not do any date calculations with durations like `48 * 60 * 60`. Those calculation will be wrong sometimes.

Comment: rmaddy. thank you.

Fogmeister, i am looking forward to see right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so say you open the app on a certain day.

You want all of the working days (Monday to Friday) for that week and all of the working days for next week also.

Right...

```
- (void)getDays
{
    NSArray *days = @[];

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    // add this week's work days to array
    days = [days arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self workDaysOfWeekFromDate:currentDate]];

    NSDate *nextWeek = [self dateWeekAfterDate:currentDate];

    // add next week's work days to array
    days = [days arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self workDaysOfWeekFromDate:nextWeek]];
}

- (NSDate *)dateWeekAfterDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    components.day = 7;

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
}

- (NSInteger)dayOfWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarWeekdayUnit fromDate:date];

    return components.weekday;
}

- (NSDate *)dayWithIndex:(NSInteger)dayIndex fromWeekOfDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSInteger dayOfWeekFromDate = [self dayOfWeekFromDate:date];

    NSInteger difference = dayIndex - dayOfWeekFromDate;

    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    components.day = difference;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
}

- (NSArray *)workDaysOfWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    // Sunday = 1
    // ...
    // Saturday = 7

    return @[
        [self dayWithIndex:2 fromWeekOfDate:date], // Monday
        [self dayWithIndex:3 fromWeekOfDate:date], // Tuesday
        [self dayWithIndex:4 fromWeekOfDate:date], // Wednesday
        [self dayWithIndex:5 fromWeekOfDate:date], // Thursday
        [self dayWithIndex:6 fromWeekOfDate:date]  // Friday
    ];    
}
```

There are several functions here. Everything happens and is finished in the `getDays` function. When that finishes the array `days` will contain NSDate objects for Monday-Friday this week and next week.

Of course, you can change the `currentDate` to be any date you want. It will always take the week from `currentDate` and the week after `currentDate`.

This will always work, with any calendar and leap years etc...

For getting the names of the dates you can do this...

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = @"EEEE";

NSString *dayName = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

The format `EEEE` means the day name. So today the `dayName` string is `Tuesday`.

```
EEEE = Tuesday
EEE = Tue
```

You could of course merge this down into one function which would have fewer lines. But I prefer having readable code.

Comment: it is quite complicated for me. i understand more of your code, but when put NSLog to see, what is in array "days", it is empty. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @SpencerReid where are you putting the log statement?

Comment: @SpencerReid and yes, dates are hard. That's why you can't just use 24*60*60.

Comment: i dont understand why monday is not 0 index. its funny. in the end of getDays function

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getDays];

}

and in the end of getDays function     NSLog(@"%@", days);

Comment: @SpencerReid ah, my mistake I update the `getDays` function. As for why Monday is not 1... no idea. Ask the guy in Apple who decided to set it that way. It's in the documentation. Sunday is 1.